# How to allocate unallocated disk space with GParted Live?

Tags: partitioning, gparted

I am trying to increase VMWare Ubuntu disk size. I already expand it. Now I read need to use GParted Live. I already mounted it:

[image: Nautilus screenshot]

But how do I run GParted Live? Which file should I double click? I also tried to run GParted partition editor but I cannot do anything to gray unallocated space. I want my Ubuntu have more space, so how do I bring the gray area to Ubuntu?

[image: GParted screenshot]

Please give clear instructions. I am extremely stupid in Ubuntu.

Comment: please i have been clicking a lot but i still cannot give the grey area to my ubuntu

Comment: GParted-live is a "live CD", which means that you boot to it.  When you boot to it, you should get a desktop with a GParted icon that you can double-click.  A live CD is a nice way to run GParted, because the program won't be running off the hard disk that you're trying to modify.  You could also install the `gparted` package in Ubuntu, but then you wouldn't be able to modify Ubuntu's partitions safely.

Comment: The short answer is: **move** sda2 right, to the end of the disk, and **resize** sda1 maximum to the right to take up free space.

Answer (score 1):

You might look at the following article to see how to configure VMWare to boot GParted Live: [How to: Use Gparted, VMWare to Increase /dev/sda Partition (LVM)](http://www.infopackets.com/news/9831/how-use-gparted-vmware-increase-devsda-partition-lvm).  You can ignore the LVM stuff, but pay attention to setting the bios.bootDelay = "5000" and "Use ISO image file" to boot GParted Live.

The steps in GParted Live are:

1. Grow the end of the Extended partition sda2 to the end of the disk.
2. Move swap logical partition sda5 to the end of the disk.
3. Shrink the start of the Extended partitoin sda2 to be next to the swap partition (leave 1 MiB of unallocated space for the EBR needed in an MSDOS partition table).
4. Grow the end of the ext4 primary partition sda1 to butt up agains extended partition sda2.

Before editing your partition table I highly recommend you **make a backup of all your data** just in case anything goes wrong, such as encountering a software bug, hardware failure, or a power outage.